# SSRS - types system.string and system.datetime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My requirement is to throw an error message if start date greater than end date.

I have 2 parameters startdate & enddate which are type 'Date/Time'

in Dataset properties ->

1st Filters->

```
 Exp =format(Fields!ORDDate.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")
 Operator = =
 Value = =iif(Parameters!ValidateDateRange.Value,Parameters!pStartDate.Value,"")
```

2nd Filters->

```
  Exp =format(Fields!ORDDate.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")
  Operator = =
  Value = =iif(Parameters!ValidateDateRange.Value,Parameters!pEndDate.Value,"")
```

I have used this URL to get this done but I'm getting below error...
http://aspdotnetmyblog.blogspot.com/2015/07/sql-server-reporting-ssrs-parameter.html

An Eror occured during local report processing.
An error has occured during report processing.
The proecssing of filterexpression for the dataset 'select' cannot be performed. Cannot compare data of types system.string and system.datetime. 
Please check the data type returend by the filterexrpession.

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
= IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!pEndDate.Value, Parameters!pStartDate.Value) > 0, 1,0)
```

Comment: Where should I add this? Do I have to add this to Dataset -> Filters -> value? Replace this =iif(Parameters!ValidateDateRange.Value,Parameters!pEndDate.Value,"") with your statement?